# What's a good trophy army for a town hall 8?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've maxed out my troops for town hall 8 and I'm trying to do a big push, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you and how you like to play...
until you reach crystal 2 or 1 you can go with anything you want ( giant-healer would be good ), But after Crystal 1 and master you can't win attacks with giants ( even giant 6 can't go much further )

If you have dark elixir then you can go with Hog rider and 3 healing spell too (just level 3 or higher )

alternative plan is to go with archers and barbarians, just hit Town Halls or clear 50 % of your opponent's base.

Answer (score 1):

Offensive:

- 15 wizards
- 13 gaints
- 8 wall breakers
- 1 healer
- 9 barbs
- 5 minons
- The rest archers

2 heal 1 rage
So, to utilize this army, you will need to start by taking out air defense, so that your healer can heal your wizards and giants.
First, bait the CC and BK. Use barbs to bait and the minions to take cc troops/BK out. Works for archer queen too, except she can shoot minions out of the sky.
Next, what you want to do is find the spot of the base easiest to attack, so look for exposed AD, or no AD covering that area at all.
Drop 2-3 giants toward the wall you want to attack, then 2-3 wall breakers.
Then, drop the rest of your giants and let them start entering the base. Then, place your healer to start healing them.
If the AD Is 2 layers deep, use a heal spell on your giants and maybe a rage to help. Once the AD is down, drop the healer and let them go to work.
Once the giants start taking the fire, use archers and barbs to take out buildings that might distract the wizards and look for giant bombs or traps that will ruin your raid. This ensures the wizards go into the center of the base, not around it.
The army should rip through the rest of the base, and drop wall breakers as needed to move the raid along.
You can also put the barb king with the wizards, as he will take most of the fire from cannons and archer towers until he goes down.
This usually gets me a 2 star, if it goes correctly. This strategy got me to crystal, so i hope it will help you too!

Answer (score 0):

I would say using balloons and minions. It got me to crystal 2. After that I used a hog raiding strategy. With the balloon strategy use 28 balloons and 30 minions. Also bring 3 healing spells. Find bases with the air defenses outside of the core and then do a line of balloons on one side. Place a healing spell where they are going. Then place minions behind them to clean up what they don't get.
 With the hog raiding strategy you will want 20 hogs, preferably level 3+. Also 12 wizards, and the rest 50-50 archers and barbs. Bring 3 healing spells. Lure cc troops and heroes (which should be the first thing you do in any raid) using barbs and archers. After that place your hogs all together and place a healing spell where they are headed. Save the other 2 healing spells for when you need them for like when the hogs are near wiz towers or under fire from an xbow and need the extra health. Then use the wizards and remaining archers/barbarians to clean up and get 50% and/or the town hall. I hope this helped.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest using a more or less expensive army.
16 wizards
2 golems
8 wall breakers
4 barbarians (for luring)
The rest archers

Comment: Why would you use such an army?  Arqade isn't just about giving a suggestion, but explaining *why* you would use something.  That's what turns an answer into a good answer.